# Sites with more upvotes

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

If you go to the main page of [tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) (do these Stack Exchange sites have a name?), you see many, many questions have a lot of upvotes and views.

On [the mathematics site](https://math.stackexchange.com/), however, it seems there are a lot fewer upvotes and (it seems to me) fewer views on average for a question, too.

Go to [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and on the "interesting" tab--woah! A whole list of questions with 0 upvotes, 0 answers, and under 10 views. Granted, there are a bunch of green boxes (for the questions with answers), but it seems much of what's on the front page is pretty low-profile.

Why does it seem as if the more active sites (Mathematics seems to have done better than Tex/Latex according to Area 51) have less activity per question? Even the pretty new Physics beta site has more views per question than many of the Stackoverflow questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tex has done quite well in the last week, however Maths gets more than twice the traffic that tex does and that makes a very big difference. It also happens to get more than twice the volume of questions and answers.

You are correct people are proportionally voting more on the tex site then on the maths site, as to why? I think that is a question for maths meta site.

Stack Overflow is in totally different ball game, the changes to the front page (which only affect Stack Overflow) are documented here: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/

Comment: Oh, no wonder... but why aren't other SE sites having the same "interesting" tab as Stackoverflow?

Comment: @wrongusername Other sites don't have the level of activity as Stack Overflow. The interesting tab was created because Stack Overflow questions weren't getting answered because there were too many on the front page, which isn't a problem on other sites.